# php exec not getting whole output

Tags: php, python

First of all: I read a lot of answers here for similar questions; but nothing helped.

My problem: I have a `php` file, where I execute a `python` file. The python file reads sensor values (that takes some time) and prints these values. Then, I want to echo these values in my php file.

My php file:

```
<?php
       $var1 =  shell_exec('bash -c "> /var/www/html/log.txt"');
       exec('bash -c "python /var/www/html/readTempAndHumSensor.py"',$output);
       echo count($output);
 ?>
```

My python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Adafruit_DHT

print "test"
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
gpio = 10
# read sensor values (takes aprox. 2s)
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, gpio)
# Output
print int(temperature*10)
print int(humidity*10)
```

In `$output`, *test* is stored but not the other values. Note: it takes about 2s to read the sensor data

Comment: Why the count ()?

Comment: Why are you using `bash` to empty a file? Just use `file_put_contents("", "/var/www/html/log.txt");`

Comment: @nogad count was just in order no know the size of the array. Sorry I could leave it out in this minimal example.

Comment: And why do you use `bash -c` in your `exec()` calls? Just do `exec("python /var/www/html/readTempAndHumSensor.py")`

Comment: @Barmar good idea